# Implementing a local like/unlike feature in NextJS and making it persist between client-side routes

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a blog front-end app built using [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/) and it looks like this:
[image]

Each card here is a functional component called `PostPreview.jsx`. As you can see, each component comes with a heart icon. By default, this icon is to stay gray. However, when clicked it turns red, signifying that the post has been liked. This action only occurs if the user is logged in. If not, clicking the heart icon presents a login modal.

Right now, I'm only focussing on making the "like" persist between client-side navigations, i.e. without any interaction with the db/server.

As of now, clicking the icon, toggles the color alright. However, it fails to persist when you navigate away, say, by clicking on a post title and then hitting the back button to return to this page. What is the recommended way to achieve this functionality?

The entire codebase can be found at my repo here: https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/tree/master/web

The code for the component in question (`PostPreview.jsx`) is at: https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/blob/master/web/components/blog/PostPreview.jsx

The site is live at https://www.schandillia.com/blog.

I understand I could use Redux, but not sure how to prevent the value from being reset upon each re-render even when using Redux.

**Illustrating the problem better**

Visit blog page; several instances of component (`PostPreview`) render for the first time:

1. Receive array of post "likers" via the `likedBy` prop object.
2. Retrieve logged-in user's ID from the Redux store via `userInfo.userID`.
3. Look up `userInfo.userID` against the `likedBy.readers` array of IDs.
4. If user ID exists in `readers` array, post is liked, set `liked` to `error` to turn the heart icon red and push post's `id` to the `likedPosts` redux store.
5. If user ID doesn't exist in `readers` array, leave `liked` to `inherit` to leave it gray and remove post's `id` from the `likedPosts`redux store.

Like a post; click the heart icon:

1. Set `liked` to `error` to turn the heart icon red.
2. Push post's `id` to the `likedPosts`redux store.

Unlike a post; click the heart icon:

1. Set `liked` to `inherit` to turn the heart icon red.
2. Remove post's `id` from the `likedPosts`redux store.

Now click any link on page to navigate away from the page (client-side routing, no server contact here). Then hit the browser's `back` button to return to the blog page.

At this point, the component (`PostPreview`) re-renders and the redux store will be reset in accordance with the original `likedBy` prop object. This, of course, means that all the changes since the first render are gone. This is where I need help. How would you handle such a situation where user interactions like likes and dislikes have to be persisted across client-side navigations and also honored across re-renders?

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways:

1) Simple: By using local storage you can write array of likes

```
likes: [likedPostId1, likedPostId2, ...]
```

And then in PostPreview check if current card id included in likes array

```
let isLiked = likes.includes(currentPostId);
```

2) Right: By using Redux, it's the same way, but you'll store likes array in Redux and use for page navigation [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/).
It's essential to understand how navigation works in SPA

Comment: Only problem I see either way is the LocalStorage/Redux data getting reset with every component re-render. So the first time the component renders, it receives the likes array (array of people who liked the post) as a prop. Then I add this array to the LocalStorage or Redux store for future reference. This stored array updates when I like/dislike a post. Now I navigate away to another page. Then when I hit "back" to return to the prev. page, the PostPreview components re-render and the initial assignment happens all over again. This undoes any updates I might've made the last time I was there.

Comment: @TheLearner, I usually use redux-persist (https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) if I want persistance on page reload or page refresh.

Comment: My issue is not with page-refresh because in those cases a server call would ensure the correct data is represented in the browser. Here, I'm speaking of client-side routing with no intervening server request.

Answer (score 0):

For simple SPA implementation:

1. Simple solution would be to just use Context API with hooks (refresh will reset it)
   1a. Another simple solution is to use LocalStorage with hooks (refresh or back button will persist it)
2. Than you could refactor it into REDUX (a lot of boilerplate) 
   2a. so maybe you could just use GraphQL as an app state

Here is an article explaining how to do that highlighting Redux vs hooks with Context API:

https://www.sitepoint.com/replace-redux-react-hooks-context-api/

Also it's worth to note that REDUX or GraphQL will not persist it itself between refreshes

Answer (score 0):

```
4. If user ID exists in readers array, post is liked, set liked to error to turn the heart icon red and push post's id to the likedPosts redux store.

5. If user ID doesn't exist in readers array, leave liked to inherit to leave it gray and remove post's id from the likedPosts redux store.
```

You should wrap #4. and #5. as one action in redux store.

```
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
        onUpdateLikedPosts: (data) => dispatch(actions.updateLikedPostsAction(data))
      };
    };
```

And, Execture the function at when component of PostPreview is mounted.

```
    const componentDidMount() {
        this.props.onUpdateLikedPosts(data)
    }
```